# Where to make http request on react component

Tags: reactjs

Component is a key concept on reactjs. It renders the dom element based on its state or props. My case is that a component needs to render some values which are from http response. I don't know where I should call the http request method during component lifecycle. Should I call the http request on componentWillMount() method? Since the http request is async call, it will not stop the component lifecycle process. How to handle that the component render method is called before the http response? Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Fire an HTTP request in `componentDidMount` and render a spinner instead of actual content until you receive an answer.

Comment: what is the different if I call it on componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount?

Comment: `componentWillMount` occurs before the first `render()` call, while `componentDidMount` just after that so you want the first one

Comment: I know the order different. But I want to know why you think I should put http request on componentDidMount(). Is there  a reason for that? I just want to understand more. Thanks.

Comment: Because happens before, and if you're very very lucky, there are chances for the render method to happen after the request finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting on a sensible spot since (in my experience) there is much room for improvement when it comes to handling async/external calls in react. The easiest (as in simplicity or low complexity) way to do it is as you said, in `componentWillMount`.

Despite when/where the http request gets fired, a common pattern is to render a spinner until `componentWillUpdate` decides there is enough data to render the actual component.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My concern is that if I do it in componentWillMount I still need to handle data-not-ready on render() method right?

Comment: Right, for example by checking for the `isReady` prop in the state, which could be set by the http callback